# Detect a click outside of an element

Tags: ionic-framework, events

There is some components in Ionic that do not provide an event that is emitted when focus is lost.

For example `ion-input` provides `ionBlur`. On the other hand there is other elements like `ion-content` where I need to detect an outside click, but without knowing which event to use.

Is there a way to achieve that without being limited to [the proposed events](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/content#events) in the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

I found [this article](https://christianliebel.com/2016/05/angular-2-a-simple-click-outside-directive/) that shows a way to use a custom directive to detect an outside click:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {
    constructor(private _elementRef : ElementRef) {
    }

    @Output()
    public clickOutside = new EventEmitter();

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
    public onClick(targetElement) {
        const clickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
        if (!clickedInside) {
            this.clickOutside.emit(null);
        }
    }
}
```

The directive can then be used this way, after declaring it in the concerned module:

```
<!-- HTML Template -->
<ion-content (clickOutside)="handleOutsideClick()"><!-- ... --></ion-content>

<!-- Typescript code -->
handleOutsideClick() {
    //Handle My outside Click
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, It's been 7 months since asked.

Stucked with the same issue; this solved the issue

**TS**

```
@ViewChild('content') content: ElementRef

@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  andClickEvent(event) { 
    if (!this.content.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
      if (!this.navCtrl.isTransitioning() && this.navCtrl.getActive()) {
        this.close()
      }
    }
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-content #content>
```